# Is this a good criteria to use static function?

Tags: python

When adding a new function to a class, I often am not sure whether I should use static function or class function in a class. One criteria I often use to judge the uses of static methods is to see whether a function needs to access its instance variable. If not, I tends to use static function. For example:

```
class TestStaticMethod(object):
    self.name = 'static_method_tester'

def test_static_method(spans, doc):

    for span in spans:
       if TestStaticMehtod.is_ne(span, doc):
          # do something here

@staticmethod
def is_ne(spans, doc):
   # do something, no need to access TestStaticMethod's variables, "name", etc.
```

Is this a good example of using static function? If yes, the criteria is simple to follow.

Comment: I think that's not a bad criteria, as long as it still makes sense for the method to belong to the class in the first place, rather than just being an independent function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a static method and a classmethod is that the former gets the class as a first argument. This can for example be used if the method should create a instance of the class.

If that's not needed you can stick with the static method. Or you can think about defining the function just outside the class.

Comment: If this can be the criteria, it seems a lot of functions can be static function. Would that make multiprocessing code more difficult to control?

Comment: @AbigailMinNM If a lot of functions can be static functions, that's a indication of bad object-oriented-design. Objects should encapsulate state and work with this. If that's not the case, maybe the functions should not be bind to an object, but instead should be grouped in a module.